# Limits to Telegram API get_entity requests

Tags: telethon

my app listen requests with telegram messages URL inside and process messages in loop:
get entity for group
search +/- 2 messages from target message
get entity for each recieved message author (in fact find entity to each uniqual from_id)

I use client.get_messages() and client.get_entity() methods ans sleep 10-15 secs between each loop.

And after 2-3 hours without any alerts (floodwait to 10sec or 5 minuts) I getting floodwait error with insane timeout (~22 hours).
I not trying to send spam, in fact I don`t sent any messages at all .

Where I can find limits to use get_entity methods?
Or may be using this method is overkill and user info may be finded someother method

Comment: Do you actually need the entity? Or just the access hash?

Comment: actually I need username/firstname/loastname of author.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to take a look at the Telethon [documentation](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.users.UserMethods.get_entity): in there there are a few tips that let you avoid the limits using `get_entity` combined with `get_input_entity`.

Comment: Thx for you your attention, but get_input_entity returns InputPerr object, that not contains something exept user ID and access hash, and I need username/firstname/lastname

Comment: use get_entiyty with user_id spents API call, 
use get_input_entiyty with user_id didn't spents API call, but dont return anything new exept access hash, 
use get_entiyty with inputPeer object (returned by get_input_entity(user_id))  spents API call 

May be I miss some important method, that get user information from post, that I already got?